# Nginx put POST/GET request body to variable

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I have an openresty server with a single location, in which I need to RPUSH POST/GET request body to the redis DB.

Here's a config snippet:

```
map $request_method $query {
    "GET"           $request;
    "POST"          $request_body;
}

...

location /test {
    redis2_query rpush $key $query;
    redis2_pass redis6379:6379;
}
```

But, if it gets POST request, `$query` seems to be empty.

`access_by_lua 'ngx.req.read_body()';`

and

`echo_read_request_body;`

doesn't seems to help. Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set $query "";

rewrite_by_lua '
    local method = ngx.var.request_method
    if method == "POST" then
        ngx.req.read_body()
        local data = ngx.req.get_body_data()
        ngx.var.query = data.."&ng_ua="..ngx.var.http_user_agent.."&ng_ip="..ngx.var.remote_addr.."&ng_ip="..ngx.var.time_local
    elseif method == "GET" then
        local data = ngx.var.query_string
        ngx.var.query = data.."&ng_ua="..ngx.var.http_user_agent.."&ng_ip="..ngx.var.remote_addr.."&ng_ip="..ngx.var.time_local
    end
';
```

Comment: No explain ?? Im confused maan

Comment: @AnasFanani what code line you can't understand here?